# Document type “script” - what is it?

Tags: java, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

Trying to download docs from the Google Docs using Java client library and getting some documents with type "script".

What is this type and what is the proper way to handle such kind of files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are Apps Script files. Go to [script.google.com](http://script.google.com) to create a new Apps Script project.

You can learn everything about Apps Script on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/

Comment: Is there any way to export those files using normal Gdocs List Api ?

Comment: Currently, Apps Script files cannot be imported nor exported.